# which is correct while using "as" singly

Tags: grammar

Here it's supposed to be "as...as" clause but it is without context can anyone help me thanks in advance 
Nikkie is a lively person ---- sister.
a)as her b)as is her c)so

Comment: This appears to be an exam question, but none of the choices offered would be correct, as "Nick" is a masculine first name.

Comment: Oh not Nick it was Nikkie or something I just had the photo but it was dim so.. I will edit the name to Nikkie I guess because the possessive doesn't match.. And I think the options aren't correct too because the answer should be:Nikkie is a lively person as her sister is. or Nikkie is as lively as her sister ..I chose a) option :( I was stressed so hurried to write it,

Comment: If you change the name to Nikkie, or another female name, option b) is the correct one: "as is her sister". Glad you're here on ELU, but before you post your next question, you should have a look at the "Help Center" to see the guidelines for questions posted on this site. Exam questions are not really encouraged. Stick with the site, and you'll learn a lot!

Comment: can you explain? I searched on Google and found somewhere on Quora or something that it was informal and there were no such mentions on Google but thanks for the help <3 I know it now

Comment: @IsabelArcher And *why* exactly can't a female be named Nicholas? Are you promoting *gender stereotypes*? You must be a real *bigot*. (sarcasm)